# Is there a way of getting the main thread executor for sparkjava / embedded jetty server?

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty, embedded-jetty, spark-java

I am using SparkJava to make a website. Currently it has an account management system. I have a controller, `LoginController` that makes a request to the database asynchronously and returns `ListenableFuture<Account>`.

The account manager call is made inside of a `Route` in my `LoginController`, however I want to only redirect the user into the site (sync) once the `Account` has been grabbed (async).

I know I can do `returnedFuture.addListener(runnableThatRedirectsUser, <executor>)`, but how can I get the `<executor>` for the main/sync thread in sparkjava/jetty?

Any help/advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my fault. Realised that each request in sparkjava is a new thread (or at least there is a ThreadPool)... so I don't have to worry about returning to the main thread or having an asynchronous thread for database tasks!

Comment: For Jetty each dispatch of a request is handled by a thread, but the request doesn't have to hold onto that thread for the lifetime of the request exchange. Jetty can/and does have requests that have no active threads. As well as 1 request/response exchange can be handled by multiple different threads over its lifetime.

Answer (score -3):

Just make it static! It makes everything easier.

Tis a joke by the way